# GetObject/HeadObject block forever when key not found in aws-sdk-go

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I was using the [aws-sdk-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go) to download file from s3, however, I found that calling GetObject will block forever if the key does not exist in bucket (I found this fact from aws-cli). Could any one tell me what is going on? Here is my code snippets:

```golang
// newS3Session return a s3 session with AddrInfo
func newS3Session(addr AddrInfo) *session.Session {
    cred := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(addr.AccessKey, addr.SecretKey, "")
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:           aws.String("default"),
        Credentials:      cred,
        Endpoint:         aws.String(addr.EndPoint),
        S3ForcePathStyle: aws.Bool(false),
        DisableSSL:       aws.Bool(true),
    }))
    return sess
}

func download(_ context.Context, s *session.Session, filename string) error {
    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(s)

    file, err := os.Create(tmpPath + filename)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("file_create_error|err=%w,filename=%s", err, filename)
    }
    defer func() {
        err = file.Close()
    }()

    svc := s3.New(s)
    _, err = svc.HeadObjectWithContext(context.Background(), &s3.HeadObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(srcAddr.Bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(filepath.Join(srcAddr.FilePath, filename)),
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("file_found|filepath:%s\n", filepath.Join(srcAddr.FilePath, filename))

    n, err := downloader.Download(file, &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(srcAddr.Bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(filepath.Join(srcAddr.FilePath, filename)),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("fail_to_download_file|err=%w,filepath=%s", err,
            filepath.Join(srcAddr.FilePath, filename))
    }
    fmt.Printf("file %s downloaded, size=%dB", filename, n)
    return nil
}
```

The code works fine when the key exists in s3

Comment: "I found that calling GetObject will block forever if the key does not exist in bucket" this is 100% false.   It will be 404 if the user has list bucket privileges,  otherwise 403.  This almost certainly has to do with the behavior of your custom endpoint

Comment: @DanielFarrell Hi, thanks for your reply. I think this is caused by the privileges on my local machine because it works well in other test environment.

Answer (score 0):

I did experience similar issue too, and this was the problem -  https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/38638

I was able to bypass the aws error:

```
if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok && (awsErr.Code() == "Forbidden" || awsErr.Code() == "NotFound") {
    return false, nil
} else if err != nil {
    return false, err
} else {
    return true, nil
}
```